# Mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY несколько полей

Tags: php, mysql

Как обновить несколько полей а не одно при DUPLICATE KEY

псевдокод:

```
INSERT INTO user_prices (goods_id, users_id, price, pricelists_id) 
VALUES ' . implode(',', $chank) . ' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE price=VALUES(price{pricelist_id});
```

Прошу обратить внимание на окончание sql запроса. Нужно обновит И **price** И **pricelist_id** одним запросом

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html Синтаксис UPDATE (как самостоятельно, так и в составе ODKU) один и тот же, `assignment` в `assignment_list`разделяются запятыми.

Comment: не согласен! если самостоятельная вставка то нужно использовать stat1 = stat1 а если в группе то для одного из группы то stat1 =VALUES(stat1)

Comment: Функция VALUES() определена ТОЛЬКО для секции ODKU. А нужна она исключительно потому, что в этой секции есть два одноимённых значения, из которых старое - приоритетно. Но никто не мешает и там выполнить `stat1 = stat1` - только какой в том смысл?

Comment: То есть Вы утверждаете, что если выполнить запрос с stat1 = stat1 то будет присвоено "старое"  значение, а   stat1 =VALUES(stat1) то "новое"?

Comment: Да, конечно! именно так и произойдёт...

Comment: Спасибо Вам за пояснение!

Comment: Впрочем, я знаю только одно вменяемое применение такому присвоению. Если в таблице есть автообновляемое поле штампа времени (ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), но нужно, чтобы в случае ODKU оно НЕ было обновлено, то именно переприсвоение старого значения и позволяет "отключить" автообновление для этого поля в этом запросе.

Comment: старое значение можно присвоить когда нужно что-то типа: ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE

Comment: Такого нет. Есть `INSERT IGNORE` - но он полностью игнорит ошибки дублирования. Я говорю о случае, когда при дублировании некоторые значимые поля надо обновить, а вот штамп времени оставить старым, не дав ему автоматически обновиться.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235501/mysql-insert-row-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-columns

```
INSERT INTO tb (name, date, stat1, stat2, stat3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stat1 = stat1 + VALUES(stat1), stat2 = stat2 + VALUES(stat2), stat3 = stat3 + VALUES(stat3)
```